# Cluster point of the function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Assume $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function define $f$ has dens graph on $(2,3)$ and $0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus(2,3).$ Now, let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ such that $f(a)<f(b).$ Since $\{(x,f(x)\colon x\in(2,3)\}$ is dense in $(2,3)\times \Bbb R$ then there are $c<d$ in $(2,3)$ such that $$f(a)<f(c)<f(d)<f(b).$$ I understand this part.
Now, Can I replace the density of the graph by $0$ is cluster point of $f$ at the endpoint and still find such $c<d$ in $(2,3)$ and $f(c)<f(d).$ I understand the cluster point but I did not how it will help to ensure that. I would be hug help if you can help with that

Comment: No: you might have $f(x)=0$ for $x<\frac73$ and $x>\frac83$ and $f(x)=1$ for $\frac73\le x\le\frac83$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you for your comment. you meant we could not replace density by cluster point ti ensure that

Comment: Correct: you need much more than just cluster point.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, What conditions can be used to ensure that and they are weaker than density

Comment: $f[(2,3)]$ probably needs to be a densely ordered subset of $\Bbb R$, meaning that between any two points of $f[(2,3)]$ there is another point of $f[(2,3)]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , how about the function satisfies the intermediate value theorem ?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, In my case, my function satisfies the Intermediate value theorem. But I did not see the important of the cluster such that I can get ride of the density. Could you please show me how this can be done

Comment: If $a<b$ and $f(a)<f(b)$, let $u\in\big(f(a),f(b)\big)$; there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=u$. Then let $v\in\big(u,f(b)\big)$; there is a $d\in(c,b)$ such that $f(d)=v$. Clearly $a<c<d<b$ and $f(a)<f(c)<f(d)<f(b)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, we do not cluster point though

Comment: If your function satisfies the intermediate value theorem, $0$ doesn’t need to be a cluster point at $2$ and $3$.